# Replacement for "FOR()" macro in cyclic buffer / fifo queue array elements

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, c-preprocessor, fifo

I have FIFO of Elem structures implemented in following way:

Untill max_elems limit is reached Push() simply put given element after last one in array and increments elems (count).
If elems already reached max_elems it simulates pop by advancing head index so it behaves like a cyclic buffer.

```
struct FIFO
{
    FIFO(int mx)
    {
        head = 0;
        elems = 0;
        max_elems = mx;
        elem = new Elem[max_elems]; 
    }

    int elems;
    int max_elems;

    Elem* elem; // [max_elems]

    int head;

    void Push( const Elem* e )
    {
        // int i = (elems+head) % max_elems;

        int i = elems + head;
        if (i >= max_elems)
            i -= max_elems;

        elem[ i ] = *e;

        if (elems < max_elems)
            elems ++;
        else
        {
            head ++;
            if (head == max_elems)
                head = 0;
        }
    }

    Elem* GetItem(int i)
    {
        // int j = (i+head)%max_elems;

        int j = i + head;
        if (j >= max_elems)
            j -= max_elems;

        return elem + j;
    }
};
```

I need to iterate over elements in elem array very offten. And I desperately have to keep performance at MAX. 
So instead of using GetItem inside regular for() I made a FOR macro:

```
#define FOR(fifo,elem,from,count,code) \
if (fifo->head==0) \
{ \
    int to = from+count;
    for (int i = from; i<to; i++) \
    { \
        Elem* elem = fifo->elem+i; \
        code \
    } \
else \
{ \
    int f = from+fifo->head; \
    if (f>=fifo->max_elems) \
        f-=fifo->max_elems; \
    int to = min(f + count, fifo->max_elems); \
    for (int i = f; i<to; i++) \
    { \
        Elem* elem = fifo->elem+i; \
        code \
    } \
    to = count - (to-f); \
    for (int i = 0; i<to; i++) \
    { \
        Elem* elem = fifo->elem+i; \
        code \
    } \
}
```

this is how I can use it

```
void main()
{
    FIFO buf(10000);
    Elem e;

    buf.Push(&e);
    buf.Push(&e);
    // ...

    FOR (  buf, pe , 11, 5009, { pe->do_something(); } );
}
```

I hate this macro because it is not possible to debug 'code' inlined in it.

### So finaly my question is:

Is there any more elegant way to make such 'FOR' but not as a macro?

Comment: Is this [tag:c]?  The keyword `new` and function definition within struct definition don't look like right to me.

Comment: So did you really determine that making the `FOR` a function was too slow?  It shouldn't really have too much overhead if your `count` is high.  In the case of a function, `code` would be replaced by a function pointer.

Comment: My first attempt was regular for() with % operator to wrap indexes. It was waaaaay to slow. Then I replaced % with if i>max_elems it was muuuch better. Using this macro gives me about over 5x faster code if 'code' is simple enough like: {e->val++;} This performance is what I'd like to keep, but not being able to debug something is way worse than few cpu ticks.

Comment: When you used the regular `for()`, did you have your compiler's optimization turned on?

Comment: Yes, I compile under MSVC Release Win32 with PDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the c++ way is to replace horrid macros like this with template functions, which can be debugged (and tested).

EDIT: as requested, here's a first attempt at replacing the macro with a function. In fact no templates were needed - a std::function (which can be initialised from a lambda) suffices:

```
void for_elems_in_fifo(FIFO* fifo,int from,int count,std::function<void(Elem&)> code)
{
    if (fifo->head==0)
    {
        int to = from+count;
        for (int i = from; i<to; i++)
        {
            Elem* elem = fifo->elem+i;
            code(*elem);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int f = from+fifo->head;
        if (f>=fifo->max_elems)
            f-=fifo->max_elems;
        int to = min(f + count, fifo->max_elems);
        for (int i = f; i<to; i++)
        {
            Elem* elem = fifo->elem+i;
            code(*elem);
        }
        to = count - (to-f);
        for (int i = 0; i<to; i++)
        {
            Elem* elem = fifo->elem+i;
            code(*elem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a sketch of such template func. I don't know how to do it with max_elems comming from outside my library.

Comment: example added to answer as requested

Comment: thank you Richard! I thought you mean to template FIFO, and I was wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to go fully STL-style: create a `FIFOIterator` class and provide the `begin()` and `end()` functions on the FIFO class. Here is an (incomplete) example:

```
template <typename T>
struct FIFO
{
    class FIFOIterator
    {
    public:
        using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using reference = T&;
        using pointer = T*;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

        FIFOIterator() :
            fifo{ nullptr },
            index{ 0 }
        {}

        FIFOIterator(FIFO & fifo_in, size_t index_in) :
            fifo{ &fifo_in },
            index{ index_in }
        {
        }

        T & operator*()
        {
            return (*fifo)[index];
        }

        FIFOIterator & operator++()
        {
            ++index;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator==(const FIFOIterator & rhs)
        {
            return index == rhs.index;
        }

        bool operator!=(const FIFOIterator & rhs)
        {
            return !(operator==(rhs));
        }

    private:
        size_t index;
        FIFO * fifo;
    };

    using iterator = FIFOIterator;

    FIFO(size_t mx) :
        head{ 0 },
        elems{ 0 },
        max_elems{ mx },
        elem{ new T[max_elems] }
    {
    }

    ~FIFO()
    {
        delete[] elem;
    }

    size_t elems;
    size_t max_elems;

    T* elem; // [max_elems]

    size_t head;

    void push(const T & e)
    {
        // int i = (elems+head) % max_elems;

        if (elems < max_elems)
        {
            ++elems;
        }

        elem[head] = e;

        ++head;
        if (head == max_elems)
        {
            head = 0;
        }
    }

    T & operator[](size_t i)
    {
        size_t offset{ head };
        if (elems < max_size)
        {
            offset = 0;
        }
        size_t j = i + offset;
        if (j >= max_elems)
        {
            j -= max_elems;
        }

        return elem[j];
    }

    FIFOIterator begin()
    {
        return FIFOIterator(*this, 0);
    }

    FIFOIterator end()
    {
        return FIFOIterator(*this, elems);
    }
};
```

Using the above, it is possible to use STL algorithms with your FIFO, e.g.,

```
template <typename T>
void printFifo(FIFO<T> & fifo)
{
    std::for_each(fifo.begin(), fifo.end(), [](T & val) { std::cout << val << ", "; });
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

A couple of things to note:

- I have turned `FIFO` into a templated class - you could do this without it being templated (though I would template it, so that I can reuse it for other element types)
- I have replaced `int` with `size_t` as this is the canonical size type
- I have not tested the performance of this code (though I expect it will be fairly good)
- Really, you should create the const accessor `const T & FIFO::operator[](size_t) const` and associated `const_iterator` (hence this example is not complete)
- You ***really should*** also implement FIFO's copy constructor and copy assignment operator, even if you just declare them private, as the class is not safe to copy in its present form (in either my example or yours)
- You ***really should*** make your data members private and provide accessor functions
- Even if you do nothing else that I have recommended ***please*** implement the `FIFO` destructor to delete the memory allocated in the constructor, otherwise you will leak memory.